# PyInstaller exe has seg fault, source code does not

Tags: python-3.x, centos7, pyinstaller

I'm working on packaging a machine learning codebase that has many dependencies on modern machine learning libraries (sklearn, xgboost, tensorflow, pandas, and the like).  We are trying to bundle the codebase into a single folder containing an executable and additional binaries needed for running (shared libraries).  To do this, we're trying to use PyInstaller.

I am able to successfully create an executable on MacOS (mojave 10.14.6) and CentOS 7.7.  I'm using conda (4.7.12) to help manage virtual environments, and Python 3.6.6.  On both platforms, I can run the code from source (i.e., not the exe created by PyInstaller) and everything runs normally.  Running the executable on MacOS works normally.  However, running the executable on CentOS ends with a seg fault (it's unclear where this is actually happening).

Here is the output of build process on CentOS:

```
54 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
54 INFO: Python: 3.6.6
55 INFO: Platform: Linux-3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.7.1908-Core
58 INFO: UPX is not available.
59 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in /root/.cache/pyinstaller
60 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/jloy/amb-rte', '/home/jloy/amb-rte']
60 INFO: checking Analysis
61 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
61 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
64 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
66 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3879 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'amb_pacman.settings.rte'
4869 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'amb.settings.rte'
5161 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
6708 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
7724 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
8357 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
8358 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir '/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/fake-modules'
37973 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'amb.evolve.neat.core.indexer'
38049 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'amb_utils.settings.rte'
39648 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'sklearn.utils._cython_blas'
39648 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs'
39648 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree'
39649 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'sklearn.tree._utils'
39734 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'multiprocessing.forking'
39734 ERROR: Hidden import 'multiprocessing.forking' not found
39734 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'multiprocessing.freeze_support'
39734 ERROR: Hidden import 'multiprocessing.freeze_support' not found
39734 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'numpy.type'
39735 ERROR: Hidden import 'numpy.type' not found
39735 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
39762 INFO: Caching module hooks...
39768 INFO: Analyzing /home/jloy/amb-rte/runtime_engine.py
51355 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
68391 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
101910 INFO: Loading module hooks...
101911 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-IPython.py"...
101926 INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
101941 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
101941 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
101941 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools
101941 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
101943 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
101957 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
101972 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
101986 INFO: Excluding import 'gtk'
102000 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
102458 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
102483 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
102484 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
102496 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
102506 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
102521 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
102522 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
102534 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
102534 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
102535 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
102547 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
102548 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
102548 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
102559 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
102559 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
102708 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
102832 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
103067 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
103489 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
103489 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
103656 INFO: checking Tree
103657 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
103657 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
103665 INFO: checking Tree
103666 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
103666 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
103670 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
103672 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
103978 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
103979 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
104077 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-h5py.py"...
104079 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-importlib_metadata.py"...
104082 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jedi.py"...
104127 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jinja2.py"...
104157 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
104159 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-llvmlite.py"...
104161 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.backends.py"...
104933 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
105583 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
106039 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named 'gtk'
106663 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    The Gtk3 backend requires PyGObject or pgi
107050 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
107625 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx'
/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
108462 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
    No module named 'ipykernel'
109134 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
109487 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
110150 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
110519 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
111089 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
111452 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
112115 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
112741 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython>=2.9
113172 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
113603 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
114279 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
114704 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed
115090 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named 'gobject'
115640 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
116288 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
116838 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
117424 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
117967 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
118562 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
118991 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numba.py"...
119014 INFO: Excluding import 'IPython'
119033 INFO:   Removing import of IPython.paths from module numba.caching
119033 INFO:   Removing import of IPython.utils.path from module numba.caching
119040 INFO: Excluding import 'scipy'
119057 INFO:   Removing import of scipy.linalg.cython_blas from module numba.targets.linalg
119057 INFO:   Removing import of scipy.linalg.cython_lapack from module numba.targets.linalg
119063 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
119229 INFO: MKL libraries found when importing numpy. Adding MKL to binaries
119230 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
119231 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pandas.py"...
120598 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-patsy.py"...
120600 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
121246 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pycparser.py"...
121247 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
121247 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pygments.py"...
123779 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytest.py"...
124808 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
124826 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.io.matlab.py"...
124827 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.linalg.py"...
124827 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.py"...
124828 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py"...
124831 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py"...
124831 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py"...
124832 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
125823 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-shelve.py"...
125824 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sklearn.metrics.cluster.py"...
125851 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation" not found!
125851 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_tools" not found!
125852 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
125944 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
125956 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-torch.py"...
125987 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
125987 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
125988 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
125988 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xgboost.py"...
126102 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
157007 INFO: Packages required by xgboost:
['numpy', 'scipy']
157271 INFO: checking Tree
157272 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
157272 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
157273 INFO: checking Tree
157273 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-03.toc is non existent
157273 INFO: Building Tree Tree-03.toc
157273 INFO: checking Tree
157273 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-04.toc is non existent
157273 INFO: Building Tree Tree-04.toc
157274 INFO: checking Tree
157274 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-05.toc is non existent
157274 INFO: Building Tree Tree-05.toc
157275 INFO: checking Tree
157275 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-06.toc is non existent
157275 INFO: Building Tree Tree-06.toc
157275 INFO: checking Tree
157275 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-07.toc is non existent
157275 INFO: Building Tree Tree-07.toc
157276 INFO: checking Tree
157276 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-08.toc is non existent
157276 INFO: Building Tree Tree-08.toc
157277 INFO: checking Tree
157277 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-09.toc is non existent
157277 INFO: Building Tree Tree-09.toc
157277 INFO: checking Tree
157277 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-10.toc is non existent
157277 INFO: Building Tree Tree-10.toc
157278 INFO: checking Tree
157278 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-11.toc is non existent
157279 INFO: Building Tree Tree-11.toc
157279 INFO: checking Tree
157279 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-12.toc is non existent
157279 INFO: Building Tree Tree-12.toc
157279 INFO: checking Tree
157280 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-13.toc is non existent
157280 INFO: Building Tree Tree-13.toc
157280 INFO: checking Tree
157280 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-14.toc is non existent
157280 INFO: Building Tree Tree-14.toc
157281 INFO: checking Tree
157282 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-15.toc is non existent
157282 INFO: Building Tree Tree-15.toc
157282 INFO: checking Tree
157282 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-16.toc is non existent
157282 INFO: Building Tree Tree-16.toc
157284 INFO: checking Tree
157284 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-17.toc is non existent
157284 INFO: Building Tree Tree-17.toc
157285 INFO: checking Tree
157285 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-18.toc is non existent
157285 INFO: Building Tree Tree-18.toc
157307 INFO: checking Tree
157307 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-19.toc is non existent
157307 INFO: Building Tree Tree-19.toc
157315 INFO: checking Tree
157316 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-20.toc is non existent
157316 INFO: Building Tree Tree-20.toc
157316 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
157838 WARNING: library user32 required via ctypes not found
159961 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
160067 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
160073 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
160078 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
160082 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
160085 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
160088 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
160092 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_certifi.py'
160096 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
160297 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography-2.5-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_constant_time.abi3.so'
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography-2.5-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so'
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography-2.5-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_padding.abi3.so'
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coverage-5.0a8-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/coverage/tracer.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/tbbpool.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by /root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2)
/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/tbbpool.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2)
/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/tbbpool.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2)
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libgcc_s.so.1'
/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by /root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2)
/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2)
/root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/../.libs/libtbb-52872150.so.2)
173700 INFO: Looking for eggs
173701 INFO: Using Python library /root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/../../../libpython3.6m.so.1.0
173911 INFO: Warnings written to /home/jloy/amb-rte/pydist/build/runtime_engine/warn-runtime_engine.txt
174792 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /home/jloy/amb-rte/pydist/build/runtime_engine/xref-runtime_engine.html
175119 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
175132 INFO: checking PYZ
175132 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
175132 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/jloy/amb-rte/pydist/build/runtime_engine/PYZ-00.pyz
188154 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/jloy/amb-rte/pydist/build/runtime_engine/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
188323 INFO: checking PKG
188324 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
188325 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
188418 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
188420 INFO: Bootloader /root/miniconda3/envs/rte/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run_d
188420 INFO: checking EXE
188420 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
188420 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
188420 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /home/jloy/amb-rte/pydist/build/runtime_engine/runtime_engine
188523 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
188535 INFO: checking COLLECT
188536 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
188536 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
193501 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

The ldd warnings and the messages about GLIBCXX do not happen for MacOS.  Either way, the process creates an executable that is runnable.

I'm very perplexed as to how it's possible I can run the code unpackaged with no problems, and at the same time, the executable fails with a seg fault.  Especially since I'm running on the exact same machine that created the executable.  That is, I'm essentially doing this:

```
$ pyinstaller mySpec.spec
$ ./dist/myExe
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.  I would be happy to provide additional information as well.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get the executable running on CentOS 7.7.  There ended up being an issue with which BLAS library numpy used.  When I forced conda to  use the openblas flavor (instead of MKL), everything worked.

I was able to figure this out by trying the same procedure on CentOS 8.  When running the executable there I got a more descriptive error, instead of just a seg fault.  The executable still crashed, but it was because it could not find the symbol `__kmpc_global_thread_num` in `libmkl_intel_thread.so`.  I started googling around and was able to find someone with a similar issue who solved it by forcing openblas over MKL.

The question still remains though: why would running from source work, but running the executable not?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a new conda environment with Python 3.5 (not 3.6 or above) and compile from it. It has worked for me in centOS 6.

You may need to add non-standard libraries (like numpy) as hidden imports for pyinstaller.

Hope it helps